# How to automatically organise your data once you have pulled together multiple sheets onto a master sheet through =Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a master sheet where I have pulled various pieces of data from other sheets. It has automatically been organised and grouped by source sheet (all source sheets are the same format), is there a way to organise it by month (column A) instead?

This is what I have used based on other tutorials:
`=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A2:H;'Sheet2'!A2:H;'Sheet3'!A2:H;'Sheet4'!A2:H;'Sheet5'!A2:H;'Sheet6'!A2:H;'Sheet7'!A2:H;'Sheet8'!A2:H;'Sheet9'!A2:H;'Sheet10'!A2:H;'Sheet11'!A2:H},"select * where Col3 is not Null")`

So It looks like this, organised by the client name:

| LAUNCH DATE | OWNER | COMPANY | ANGLE | ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| February 2022 | Tori. | Facebook | Valentines Day |  |
| June 2022 | Tori | Spotify | World Music Day |  |
| July 2022 | Tori | Spotify | Independence Day |  |
| January 2022 | Tori | Zoo | Animal Day |  |

It is organised A-Z of the sheet names that were used to create the master sheet (the same names as the company column) I want them organised by in order of launch date rather than sheet name, see launch data column where they are not in order, like this:

| LAUNCH DATE | OWNER | COMPANY | ANGLE | ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January 2022 | Tori | Zoo | Animal Day |  |
| February 2022 | Tori | Facebook | Valentines Day |  |
| June 2022 | Tori | Spotify | World Music Day |  |
| July 2022 | Tori | Spotify | Independence Day |  |

Can anyone suggest anything that could help, please? :)

Comment: as what I assume your col A has month name and may be try like this "Select Col1 Where Col1 <>''"

Comment: What do you mean by "organize it"? do you want the month column to be headers or do you want to sum by month? Providing sample data with input and expected output will clarify things.

Comment: Thank you @12Rev79 that didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gangula I have updated the original question, hope that makes more sense :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to sort it by simply adding a [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) formula like - `SORT(QUERY(...), 1, TRUE)`

This should work for you:
`=SORT(QUERY({'Sheet1'!A2:H;'Sheet2'!A2:H;'Sheet3'!A2:H;'Sheet4'!A2:H;'Sheet5'!A2:H;'Sheet6'!A2:H;'Sheet7'!A2:H;'Sheet8'!A2:H;'Sheet9'!A2:H;'Sheet10'!A2:H;'Sheet11'!A2:H},"select * where Col3 is not Null"), 1, TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! @gangula